# How do I effectively force Minitest to run my tests in order?

Tags: ruby, minitest

I know. This is discouraged. For reasons I won't get into, I need to run my tests in the order they are written.  According to the documentation, if my test class (we'll call it TestClass) extends Minitest::Unit::TestCase, then I should be able to call the public method `i_suck_and_my_tests_are_order_dependent!` (Gee - do you think the guy who created Minitest had an opinion on that one?).  Additionally, there is also the option of calling a method called `test_order` and specifying `:alpha` to override the default behavior of `:random`.  Neither of these are working for me.

Here's an example:

```
class TestClass < Minitest::Unit::TestCase

  #override random test run ordering
  i_suck_and_my_tests_are_order_dependent!

  def setup
    ...setup code
  end

  def teardown
    ...teardown code
  end

  def test_1
    test_1 code....
    assert(stuff to assert here, etc...)
    puts 'test_1'
  end

  def test_2
    test_2_code
    assert(stuff to assert here, etc...)
    puts 'test_2'
  end

end
```

When I run this, I get:

```
undefined method `i_suck_and_my_tests_are_order_dependent!' for TestClass:Class (NoMethodError)
```

If I replace the `i_suck` method call with a method at the top a la:

```
def test_order
  :alpha
end
```

My test runs, but I can tell from the `puts` for each method that things are still running in random order each time I run the tests.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If you just add test_order: alpha to your test class, the tests  will run in order:

```
class TestHomePage

def self.test_order
 :alpha
end

def test_a
 puts "a"
end

def test_b
 puts "b"
end

end
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that, as of `minitest` 5.10.1, the `i_suck_and_my_tests_are_order_dependent!` method/directive is *completely* nonfunctional in test suites using `MiniTest::Spec` syntax. The `Minitest.test_order` method is apparently not being called at all.

**EDIT:** This has been a known issue since Minitest 5.3.4: see [seattlerb/minitest#514](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/issues/514) for the blow-by-blow wailing and preening.

You and I aren't the ones who "suck". What's needed is a BDD specification tool for Ruby without the bloat of RSpec *and* without the frat-boy attitude and contempt for wider community practices of MiniTest. Does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 3):

`i_suck_and_my_tests_are_order_dependent!` may be a later addition to minitest & not available as a Ruby core method. In that case, you'd want to force use of your gem version:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'minitest'
```

Comment: Agreed; don't use the built-in minitest. Use the gem.

Comment: Aww. I loved that name.

Comment: It wasn't renamed. That PR was rejected.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the method *test_order* should be a class method and not a instance method like so:

```
# tests are order dependent
def self.test_order
  :alpha
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to interfere in this chain may be to override a class method runnable_methods:

```
def self.runnable_methods
  ['run_first'] | super | ['run_last']
end

#Minitest version:
def self.runnable_methods
  methods = methods_matching(/^test_/)

  case self.test_order
  when :random, :parallel then
    max = methods.size
    methods.sort.sort_by { rand max }
  when :alpha, :sorted then
    methods.sort
  else
    raise "Unknown test_order: #{self.test_order.inspect}"
  end
end
```

You can reorder test any suitable way around. If you define your special ordered tests with

```
test 'some special ordered test' do 
end
```

, don't forget to remove them from the results of super call.

In my example I need to be sure only in one particular test to run last, so I keep random order on whole suite and place 'run_last' at the end of it.