# Run Rake::TestTask test_files run in order

Tags: ruby, rake

I am trying to run rake specs from a test_files in sequence like say file1, file2 like in the below code, but they run randomly when I do `rake test`.

```
require 'rake/testtask'
Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
        t.test_files = [
                "specs/file1_spec.rb",
                "specs/file2_spec.rb",
                "specs/file3_spec.rb",
                "specs/file4_spec.rb",
                "specs/file5_spec.rb"]
end
```

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772890/in-ruby-how-to-i-control-the-order-in-which-testunit-tests-are-run

Comment: I mean using the Rake file, the above link shows to run within a ruby class but we have big number of tests in each of those files

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752654/how-do-i-effectively-force-minitest-to-run-my-tests-in-order for hints and bugs.